# How to change attribute min in input field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input field with arrow (up, down). Next to it I have two buttons, `+` and `-`. When I click on the input field and then click the arrow the system gets the value from dropdown list. This is ok. But when I click the second one the system doesn't get the value from the dropdown list but he add 1 value. Where is the problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#quantity_wanted").attr({
    "min": parseInt($('#group_psoft :selected').val())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="group_psoft" id="group_psoft" class="form-control attribute_select no-print">
  <option value="35" selected="selected" title="35">35</option>
  <option value="36" title="36">36</option>
  <option value="37" title="37">37</option>
  <option value="38" title="38">38</option>
  <option value="39" title="39">39</option>
  <option value="40" title="40">40</option>
</select>
<input name="qty" id="quantity_wanted" class="text" value="1" min="35" type="number">
```

Dropdownlist above product name: http://prestashop.suszek.info/pl/summer-dresses/printed-summer-dress

Comment: you also need event listener of the `change` event of `select`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a event listener to `select` so that `min` is updated every time dropdown is selected.

```
<select name="group_psoft" id="group_psoft" class="form-control attribute_select no-print" onChange='group_psoft_onChange()'>
```

In javacript add the code to change value of `min` inside function `group_psoft_onChange()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function group_psoft_onChange(){
      $("#quantity_wanted").attr({
        "min": parseInt($('#group_psoft :selected').val())
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Dosen't work. I add function group_psoft_onChange() to themes/default-bootstrap/js/product.js (in the end of file). Also I add onchange to select. Check the link above

Answer (score 0):

As Rohit Agrawal Jquery solution works well, this is a JavaScript version of the answer because you tagged JavaScript.

**Shorter version**

```js
function dropdownChanged(d){
document.getElementById("quantity_wanted").value = d.value;
}
```

```html
<select name="group_psoft" id="group_psoft" class="form-control attribute_select no-print" onchange="dropdownChanged(this)">
  <option value="35" selected="selected" title="35">35</option>
  <option value="36" title="36">36</option>
  <option value="37" title="37">37</option>
  <option value="38" title="38">38</option>
  <option value="39" title="39">39</option>
  <option value="40" title="40">40</option>
</select>
<input name="qty" id="quantity_wanted" class="text" value="1" min="35" type="number">
```

**Other option**

```js
var d = document.getElementById("group_psoft");
d.addEventListener("change",dropdownChanged);
function dropdownChanged(){
  var dropdownValue = d.options[d.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("quantity_wanted").value = dropdownValue;
}
```

```html
<select name="group_psoft" id="group_psoft" class="form-control attribute_select no-print">
  <option value="35" selected="selected" title="35">35</option>
  <option value="36" title="36">36</option>
  <option value="37" title="37">37</option>
  <option value="38" title="38">38</option>
  <option value="39" title="39">39</option>
  <option value="40" title="40">40</option>
</select>
<input name="qty" id="quantity_wanted" class="text" value="1" min="35" type="number">
```